# Android Libgdx and collision detection

Tags: android, collision-detection, libgdx

For my android game I use Libgdx and I detect the collision between Bob (Omino) and Plant (Pianta) with this code that works fine :
[image: Image1]
**Assets.class**

```
pianta = new Animation(0.5f,new TextureRegion(items, 160, 384, 64, 96),
                              new TextureRegion(items, 224, 384, 64, 96));
```

**Pianta.class**

```
public class Pianta extends GameObject {
   public static final float PIANTA_WIDTH = 2;
   public static final float PIANTA_HEIGHT = 3;
   public static float stateTime;
   public Pianta(float x, float y) {
      super(x, y, PIANTA_WIDTH, PIANTA_HEIGHT);   
      stateTime = 0;
   }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
           stateTime += deltaTime;
       }

}
```

**World.class**

```
Pianta pianta1_0 = new Pianta(x+10,2.2f);
piante.add(pianta1_0);

private void collisionPiante(){
      int len = piante.size();
      for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
         if(OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(piante.get(i).bounds,omino.bounds)){
            omino.ominoMorto();
         }
      }
   }
```

**WorldRender.class**

```
private void renderPiante() {
      TextureRegion keyFrame;
      int len = world.piante.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Pianta pianta = world.piante.get(i);            
            keyFrame = Assets.pianta.getKeyFrame(Pianta.stateTime, Animation.ANIMATION_LOOPING);
            batcher.draw(keyFrame,pianta.position.x, pianta.position.y, 2, 3);
        }


   }
```

but if you watch the image 2 below, you can see that Bob hit but there isn't collision with stone (Pietra) !!
[image: Image2]
This is the code :

**Assets.class**

```
pietra1 = new TextureRegion(items,288,416,128,64);
```

**Pietra.class**

```
public class Pietra extends GameObject {
   public static float PIETRA_WIDTH = 4;
   public static float PIETRA_HEIGHT = 2;
   public Pietra(float x, float y) {
      super(x, y, PIETRA_WIDTH, PIETRA_HEIGHT);
   }

}
```

**World.class**

```
Pietra pietra1_0 = new Pietra(x+25,2.2f);
pietre.add(pietra1_0);
private void collisionPietre(){
      int len2 = pietre.size();
      for(int l=0;l<len2;l++){
         if(OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(pietre.get(l).bounds,omino.bounds)){
            omino.ominoMorto();
         }
      }   
   }
```

**WorldRender.class**

```
private void renderPietre() {
      int len = world.pietre.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            Pietra pietra = world.pietre.get(i);            
           batcher.draw(Assets.pietra1,pietra.position.x, pietra.position.y, 4, 2);
        }
   }
```

**OverlapTester**

```
public class OverlapTester {
    public static boolean overlapRectangles (Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {
        if (r1.x < r2.x + r2.width && r1.x + r1.width > r2.x && r1.y < r2.y + r2.height && r1.y + r1.height > r2.y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Someone can tell me why the collision with the plant works fine and with stone Bob hit even if there is no collision? as you can see the code is the same, the only difference is that the plant is an animated object while the stone isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Check your OverlapTester.  This is how Libgdx does it in the Rectangle.java class:

```
/** @param rectangle the other {@link Rectangle}
 * @return whether this rectangle overlaps the other rectangle. */
public boolean overlaps (Rectangle rectangle) {
    return !(x > rectangle.x + rectangle.width || x + width < rectangle.x || y > rectangle.y + rectangle.height || y + height < rectangle.y);
}
```

Comment: Ok but I do not understand why it works well with plants animated and not with the stones ... I took the class overlaptester  from the project Superjumper made by the author of Libgdx so it should be correct....

Answer (score 2):

If I understood right **overlapRectangles** checks the case if **rectangle** is totally inside. It is not probably thing you want.

LibGDX has special functionality for collision checking. Please, check http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html

Comment: And then why the author of Libgdx have used the bounds and overlaptester class for to dectect the collision?  (overlaptetser is for a partial collision)

Comment: I also tried to intersector but also does not work :-( the problem is the same and also. I realized that the plant works because it is large 2f but if it becomes large 3f she did not work either !!!

Comment: yep. i rechecked rectangles collision. it seems to be fine... hmmm... You use GameObject class from SuperJumper example. Right? Does your object move? If yes then check that bounds is updated properly, because in the code I've found on internet (http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Game/libgdx/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/GameObject.java.htm) bounds in initialized only once in the constructor. If you change object coordinate bounds stays the same. May it cause the issue?

Comment: The bound is update into Bob.classhttp://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Game/libgdx/com/badlogicgames/superjumper/Bob.java.htm for plant and stone they are static object

Comment: Ok. If it works like this then it is fine. Have you tried to print rectangle coordinates or check them in debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to replace your OverlapTester with the Rectangle's helper function *contains*. For instance:

**World Class**

```
if(OverlapTester.overlapRectangles(piante.get(i).bounds,omino.bounds)){
    omino.ominoMorto();
}
```

Can be:

```
if (piante.get(i).bounds.contains(omino.bounds)) {
    omino.ominoMorto();
}
```