# Android Create a rectangle within an image view

Tags: android, collision-detection, area, rect

Hi i wanted to know how can I create a rectangle inside an imageview. As you can see in the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCpdT.png ) I need to create a rectangular internal and the external, this for determining the collision to the outside there are no problems, but can not seem to create the internal one. To create the internal one, I did it this way:

```
Rect r1 = new Rect(Object1.x, Object1.y, Object1.x + Bounds1.width(),  Object1.y + Bounds1.height());
```

for the internal one had thought to do the same, but halving all values, but does not work =(

Answer (score 2):

I think you must write you custom imageview extends ImageView and override onDraw method.
draw a rect on it.

Answer (score 0):

Extend a Image view. Override on Draw and draw a rectangle

```
   public class ExtendedImageView extends ImageView {
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 80, 80, paint);
   }
 }
```

Edit:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ExtendedImageView ev= new ExtendedImageView(this);
    ev.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);// set background
    setContentView(ev);
}

class ExtendedImageView extends ImageView {
        public ExtendedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(300, 300, 100, 100, paint);// draw rectangle on it.
       }
     }

       }
```

Comment: thank you both, but I'm not using the OnDraw method nor Canvas, my image is not drawn, but png image in the folder drawable, there is no way to do it without using the OnDraw method and Canvas?=(

Comment: you can have a background image and draw rectangle over it. check the edit

Comment: but in this way, can check if there is intersection between two rectangles?

Comment: yes you can. All you need is co- ordinates. there are game libraries than help detect collision detection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537322/android-libgdx-and-collision-detection.

Comment: thanks for the link, but at the moment I would like to achieve something much simpler, just to learn, I just started to learn Android^^