# one imageview multiable areas

Tags: android, imageview

what I am trying to do is to put one image view just say like this image
[image]

so when i click on the rectangle it will take me to another activity named lets say rectangle
and when i click on the circle it will take me to the circle activity
and so on
i searched a lot and found nothing
i wish someone here knows the answer to this
and also this is not my answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355313/android-create-a-rectangle-within-an-image-view)

Comment: really wow wow structure why not using canvas for it

Comment: " Provide details. Share your research. " please show some code you've attempted ...

Comment: actually i didn't tried any code because i have no idea how to start with it
but simply i need to handle only one ImageView with multiple areas???
like the user press on the left something happens
and when presses on the right side of the image something else happens
also i need to divide it into many areas

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to avoid handling the clicks outside the image area, e.g. outside the circle bounds but with in the image rect? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: something like that yes